# Webservice call not working after switching between Wifi to 3G or 3G to Wifi

Tags: android

I written a service in my app that will send lat longs to the server for every 15 seconds . the problem is:

When service started i am using wifi and making calls to server with latest lat longs for every 15 seconds it is working fine.after some time I switch off the wifi and switch on the 3g (mobile network) now the service is not reporting latest lat longs to the server.But it is working fine when switch off wifi for some time and again switch on wifi.

The service also not working fine in the vice versa that is when we are switching between 3g to wifi. But it is also not working when I am switching between 3G to 3G ie use 3G initially and switch off for some time and then switch on the 3G again ( but wifi to wifi change service is working fine.)

I don't why this abnormal scenario happening to my service.

Looking for help if any body knows about this problem.Immediate response would be appreciable.

Regards,
Kiran.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm experiencing the same problem. The only difference is that the connection is still working forming if I switch from 3g to WiFi. If I switch from WiFi to 3g, my connection hangs. I notice that my connection hangs when I call getResponseCode(). Until now, I'm looking for a solution on this.

Comment: You should post some code that shows how you are dealing with changes in connectivity. You should also have a look at the logcat and see if you are getting any errors when you switch connectivity on and off. This may improve your chances of getting some help.

Comment: this might be relevant http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2207

Comment: Hi Kiran, It would be good if you share the solution if the problem got resolved.

Comment: Switching from WiFi connection to 3g causes connection to hang:-  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242942/switching-from-wifi-connection-to-3g-causes-connection-to-hang?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for any how.

Any platform that support multiple connection then it switches to any it will not process the request to server.

You 'll need to re-request at connection lost, there is no solution for this problem.

Comment: It should be possible. There could be some limitations or bugs in android api.

Comment: @RamakrishnaNagulakonda No, you can also try in your web browser, with same. you can request with One connection (Dial-up connection) and switch between connection while it is processing to (Wifi or other), then you see the same behavior.